# how convert locations: [CLLocation] to Coordinate2D?

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, cllocation, cllocationcoordinate2d

how cat get coordinate location of didUpdateLocation delegate ?

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
```

Please Help me.Thanks

Comment: `CLLocation().coordinate` ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423504-coordinate That's a simple property. Then check the first or last value of the array?

Comment: i want fist value for first location

Comment: @user9071596, `let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D? = locations.first?.coordinate`, probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simple answer for this question in swift :

```
(locations.first?.coordinate)!
```

Comment: Why would you first use `?` and then `!`? Why not directly `locations.first!.coordinate`? or `locations[0].coordinate`?

Comment: @Sulthan Unfortunately the compiler suggests that syntax in case of accessing a non-optional property of an optional-chained expression. And many folks don't scrutinize the suggestions of the compiler 

Answer (score 1):

```
 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

 location = locations.last!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do some research before posting.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let coordinate = locations.first?.coordinate
}
```

[CLLocation Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation)

The location manager gives you an array of locations, just get the first one and then access the coordinate property.

Answer (score 0):

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: AnyObject[]!) {
        var locationArray = locations as NSArray
        var locationObj = locationArray.lastObject as CLLocation
        var coord = locationObj.coordinate

        println(coord.latitude)
        println(coord.longitude)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

`let lastLocation = locations.flatMap({ $0.coordinate }).last`